# Opacity doesn't get applied correct in C#

Tags: c#, windows, opacity

I want to change opacity of another window. I managed to change the opacity with SetWindowLong and SetLayeredWindowAttributes but it doesn’t get applied directly. When I change the opacity: the window will become transparent but when I change it again to another opacity the opacity goes away.

How is this posable and how can I solve this problem, Is this a redraw problem? I also tried to apply 2 times the same opacity; the same will happen if you do that.

This is how I change the opacity:

```
public void Opacity(IntPtr WindowHandle, byte WindowOpacity)
{
    SetWindowLong(WindowHandle, -20, GetWindowLong(WindowHandle, -20) ^ 0x080000);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(WindowHandle, 0, WindowOpacity, 0x002);
}
```

Comment: Um, the second time through, you clear the style instead of setting it. It's also poor form to mess with windows that aren't yours.